# Programmatically update background wallpaper of iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa

Is it possible to update the iOS background wallpaper now with iOS 7 programmatically?  I have several instances where users are wanting to update their wallpaper to a changing images at programmatically determined intervals.  I know that this was not supported pre 7, but I am not sure if it has been added and cannot yet find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is not, and will likely never be, a public API for this. This is a good thing, trust me.

You can save a picture to the user's photo album, which should then be easy for them to set that as their wallpaper.

Comment: Thanks.  This is unfortunate as I have had so many users request background updates.  It's definitely something users want, but there are some "control problems" that Apple and some developers here as I can see that are preventing it.  I can see why they wouldn't do it, but it's akin to arguments against guns or allowing people to have kitchen utensils. :)  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Apps are sandboxed and do not change system settings in any way.