# Wallpaper on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8

Is There a way to change the iPhone Wallpaper without settings in the new iOS 8?
I need to change programmatically the wallpaper of the user. I know that other iOS doesn't allow...

if not, what are my options?

thanks

Comment: The answer is probably still no, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642587/programmatically-update-background-wallpaper-of-ios-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the Springboard background but you can't publish it on the Appstore, only on an non-official store.

This way is blocked by Apple, you can't interact with it. But if you want to know how, take a look below :

Wallpapers can be overwritten at:

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *homePath1 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackground.jpg";
NSString *homePath2 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackgroundPortrait.jpg";
NSString *lockPath1 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.jpg";
NSString *lockPath2 = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackgroundPortrait.jpg";
```

**Swift:**

```
let HomePath = "/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackground.jpg"
let HomePathPortrait = "/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/HomeBackgroundPortrait.jpg"
let LockPath = "/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.jpg"
let LockPathPortrait = "/private/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackgroundPortrait.jpg"
```

---

The **official** way to do that is adding your image on the user `Photo Library` requesting it to put in to background.